# Is there a way to query registrations to SIP domain with the API or a serverless function?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

Is there a way to query the current or recent registrations to a SIP domain with the API, or from within a serverless function?

I can do this in the console with voice - manage - SIP domains - registered SIP endpoints. I would like to be able to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible with the following snippet:

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.sip.domains.list({limit: 20})
                  .then(domains => domains.forEach(d => console.log(d.sid)));
```

You can find other languages in the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sip/api/sip-domain-resource#fetch-a-sipdomain-resource).

Comment: This shows attributes of the SIP domain, but it doesn't show the current or recent SIP registrations to the SIP domain.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use the REST API to determine if there is a specific SIP endpoint that is currently connected to a SIP domain. I had the same question and Twilio technical support said this is only available from within the console. The code provided by @IObert will list the SIP domains (i.e. xxxx.sip.twilio.com), not an active SIP endpoint (i.e. +15555555555@xxxx.sip.twilio.com)